# VS 2017: how to disable repeating auto-installation of "Hopex Module Publisher" Add-In?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, add-in, virus

Since a couple of days whenever I start VS 2017 and open a project, a message box pops up telling that "The 'HopexPackage'
 did not load correctly..."

[image].

When I look at my extensions, I can see that some Hopex add-in is really installed there:

[image]

When I uninstall the add-in, I need to re-install a couple of other add-ins (that seem to be blocked by that hopex). But when I start VS again, it is there again. I did an exhaustive search in the file system and the registry, but could not find anything relevant.

It behaves like a virus. Do we have specific VS viruses nowadays?

Perchance does anybody know this behavior or/and a recipe against it, other to completely re-install the VS?
Thanks.

Comment: In the absence of a better solution, I needed to completely uninstall the old VS 2017 Enterprise, remove all its traceable remainders, and to re-install anew. It seemed to work cleanly now, for a while, but started all over again when I touched it another time...